# How to use includeLocs in Spring Mongo Template

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

Need to write this query in spring mongo template

```
 "$geoNear": {
         "near": [ -73.9815103, 40.7475731 ],
         "spherical": true,
         "distanceField": "distance",
         "includeLocs": "locs"
      }
```

Specially **"includeLocs": "locs"** this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is currently missing. I opened [#3586](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3586) to provide support for it.
Meanwhile you could do something like the following.

```java
GeoNearOperation operation = new GeoNearOperation(query, "distance") {

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {

        Document $geoNear = super.toDocument(context);
        $geoNear.put("includeLocs", "distance.location");
        return $geoNear;
    }
}
```